# MSBuild is unable to locate the FxCop binaries

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, fxcop

When I build the project I get following error. How to fix this issue?

Error message: In order to perform Code Analysis on managed binaries, MSBuild needs to launch FxCop. MSBuild is unable to locate the FxCop binaries. Make sure Visual Studio Team Edition for Software Developers or Visual Studio Team Suite is installed and run MSBuild from within the “Visual Studio Command Prompt”

Comment: I answered before I asked you some questions, do you want to run FxCop? If yes do you have it installed on the build server? 

If you dont want FxCop to run change the property as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. In my solution the rule set is in a shared network location like bellow.

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>\\someserver\aa\bb.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

If you don't have correct credentials to access the network location you will get this error. So make sure 
**\someserver\aa\bb.ruleset** is accessible from your machine. If not 
go to run and type \\someserver\ and when the login window is prompted enter your credentials. (specially if you are from a another domain, cross domain login can fail). Once you login, the next time visual studio can happily access the network path.

Comment: It can only access the ruleset. But for each rule, it needs the corresponding DLL files (the real code that does the analysis) to be loaded, and I think that's impossible to be on a shared location on network.

Answer (score 0):

****EDIT***

This would permanently disable code analysis, if thats not what you are looking for. Dont use it.

Open the project file and replace this property

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>

with 

<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

Comment: This would permentantly disable code analysis. So not the perfect soltuion.